# How to handle deletion in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a code which should delete record from while loop if pressed button. I pass the value via $_GET, but even if it shows that array(1), then deletedID="1" my code still doesn't work end goes straight to else statement. Please could you help me on this?

```
<?php
include "delete.php";

    echo "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>xXx</th>
            <th>Expense name</th>
            <th>Expense amount</th>
            <th>Expense date</th>
            <th>Expense month</th>
        </tr>";



//do while
$expResult = "SELECT * FROM expenses";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $expResult);


  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //<td><a name='delete' href='?deletedId=$row[id]'>Delete</a></td> 
    //<td><button name'deletedId' method='POST' type='submit' 
  action='".delete($conn)."'>X</button></td>
    echo "
        <tr>

            <td><a name='delete' href='?deletedId=$row[id]'>Delete</a></td> 
            <td>" . $row["expName"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["expAmount"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["expDate"]. "</td>
            <td>" . $row["expMonth"]. "</td>
        </tr>";

 }

 } else {
 echo "0 results";
 }

    if(isset($_GET['deletedId'])) {
        $expDelete = $_GET["deletedId"];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM expenses WHERE id = '$expDelete'";
        $delete = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"; 
    }else {
        mysqli_error($conn);
        echo "wrong";
    }  

    echo "

    </table>

    ";

?>
</div>
```

Comment: check for the real error then `mysqli_error($conn)` and php's error reporting.

Comment: `if(isset($_GET['delete']) > 1)` that btw, is invalid syntax and using the wrong syntax. Plus, `href` does not bear the name attribute, inputs do.

Comment: Sorry, I used if(isset($_GET['delete']) > 0), used if(isset($_GET['delete'])), didn't helped :(

Comment: just a note : double quote and simple quote are VERY different in PHP : if using double quotes then the variable or code inside it is interpreted , but with single quote all inside is printed as literally the exact text inside the quotes , there is no interpretation ! for example if you write `$x = "<br/>";` then the code <br/> is interpreted as a line break , but if you write `$x = '<br/>';` then when you make `echo $x;` then you get `<br/>`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the note. I have solved my problem, but now I have different problem. As I try to delete thrue GET method, after click delete, the page doesn't refreshes and the loop is endles, how I could solve that??

Comment: @Rolandas please raise a new question for that

Comment: $sql = "DELETE FROM expenses WHERE id = '$expDelete'";
I think the issue is here, try tild instead of single quotes or do concatenate. I'm on my mob so I didn't even check.
$sql = "DELETE FROM expenses WHERE id = '" .$expDelete . "'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code seems to be happening with this block of code:

```
if(**isset($_GET['delete']**) > 1) {
    $expDelete = $_GET["deletedId"];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM expenses WHERE id = '$expDelete'";
    $delete = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
```

Please do a var_dump($_GET['delete']); right before your if statement. What does that output? Is that the correct result? If not, change the $_GET['delete'] with the correct one. Could it be $_GET['deleteID']? I am not sure. If you post the query string, then we can help you better.

Comment: I've updated my code, but whit the var_dump($_GET['delete']); didn't helped :( still after first deletion I get the while loop spining on the if(isset...) with deletion because GET method has the ID to delete the record that was already deleted. what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Getting : D:\xampp\htdocs\expTotal.php:44:string '2' (length=1)

Comment: Thank's this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code here

```
if(isset($_GET['deleteId'])) {
```

You are sending `deletedId` not `delete` when pressing `Delete` button

Comment: ok, thanks, now works ish.. I did that but earlyer my code was bad, after fixed, didn't tryed this way! thanks!